# What is this Java character?

Tags: java

I have this piece of code, but don't understand what this '\0' character is:

```
char[] str = new char[1];
str[0] = '\0';
```

Could someone explain it? If I print out the value of `str[0]` nothing is printed.

Comment: @hsz similar but not duplicate. Different programming language.

Comment: @Raptor It's not related to the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the character with number `0` in the ASCII table. It's called `NUL`, doesn't have a visible(printable) representation and it's used for marking the end of a String.

Note that it's different than the `null` reference in Java.

More info:

- [Null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Answer (score 2):

It's the `NUL` character. Sometimes (in some languages) used to mark for example an end of a string of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Character `\0` is control character with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code 0, which doesn't have printable representation, which explains why nothing is printed.